# Class divide header and definition file

Tags: c++

I have to divide it. This code works. However, each class definition in its own header file (.h), each class member function definitions in its own source file (.C), and the program application in its own source file. I don't know how to do that. It is not fully connected.

I get the following error:

> C:\Users\Jay Yoon\OneDrive - Parkland College\Desktop\project2.cpp|48|error: 'write_account' was not declared in this scope

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<cctype>
#include<iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

//  CLASS USED IN PROJECT

class account
{
    int acno;
    char name[50];
    int deposit;
    int ssn;
    char address[50];
    int intRate;
public:
    void create_account();  //function to get data from user
    void show_account() const;  //function to show data on screen
    void dep(int);  //function to accept amount and add to balance amount
    void draw(int); //function to accept amount and subtract from balance amount
    void report() const;    //function to show data in tabular format
    int retacno() const;    //function to return account number
    int retdeposit() const; //function to return balance amount
    int retssn() const; //function to return ssn of account
    int retintRate() const;
};         //class ends here

void account::create_account()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter The account No. :";
    cin>>acno;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Name of The account holder : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name,50);
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Address of The account holder : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(address,50);
    cout<<"\nEnter SSN of The account : ";
    cin>>ssn;
    ssn=toupper(ssn);
    cout<<"\nEnter The Initial amount(>=500 for Saving and >=1000 for current ) : ";
    cin>>deposit;
    cout<<"\nEnter The Interest Rates : ";
    cin>>intRate;
    cout<<"\n\n\nAccount Created..";
}

void account::show_account() const
{
    cout<<"\nAccount No. : "<<acno;
    cout<<"\nAccount Holder Name : "<<name;
    cout<<"\nAccount Holder's address : "<<address;
    cout<<"\nSSN of Account : "<<ssn;
    cout<<"\nBalance amount : "<<deposit;
    cout<<"\nInterest Rate : "<<intRate;
    cout<<"\nTotal Balance : "<<deposit+deposit*intRate;
}



void account::dep(int x)
{
    deposit+=x;
}

void account::draw(int x)
{
    deposit-=x;
}

void account::report() const
{
    cout<<acno<<setw(8)<<" "<<name<<setw(6)<<" "<<ssn<<setw(6)<<" "<<address<<setw(17)<<" "<<deposit+deposit*intRate/100<<setw(16)<<intRate<<endl;
}


int account::retacno() const
{
    return acno;
}

int account::retdeposit() const
{
    return deposit;
}

int account::retssn() const
{
    return ssn;
}


int account::retintRate() const
{
    return intRate;
}

//   function declaration

void write_account();   //function to write record in binary file
void display_sp(int);   //function to display account details given by user
void display_all();     //function to display all account details
void deposit_withdraw(int, int); // function to desposit/withdraw amount for given account

//   Main function

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"----------------------------------------";
        cout<<"\nWelcome to the First National Bank\n" << "of Parkland - Account transaction system ";
        cout<<"\n----------------------------------------";
        cout<<"\n\n\t01. Create Account";
        cout<<"\n\n\t02. Deposit";
        cout<<"\n\n\t03. Withdraw";
        cout<<"\n\n\t04. Select Account";
        cout<<"\n\n\t05. Print Accounts";
        cout<<"\n\n\t06. Quit";
        cout<<"\n\n\tSelect Your Option (1-6) ";
        cin>>ch;
        system("cls");
        switch(ch)
        {
        case '1':
            write_account();
            break;
        case '2':
            cout<<"\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin>>num;
            deposit_withdraw(num, 1);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout<<"\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin>>num;
            deposit_withdraw(num, 2);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout<<"\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin>>num;
            display_sp(num);
            break;
        case '5':
            display_all();
            break;
         case '6':
            cout<<"\n\n\tThanks for using bank managemnt system";
            break;
         default :cout<<"\a";
        }
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }while(ch!='8');

    return 0;
}


//    function to write in file

void write_account()
{
    account ac;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
    ac.create_account();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
    outFile.close();
}

//    function to read specific record from file

void display_sp(int n)
{
    account ac;
    bool flag=false;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\nBALANCE DETAILS\n";

        while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        if(ac.retacno()==n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(flag==false)
        cout<<"\n\nAccount number does not exist";
}


//    function to display all accounts deposit list

void display_all()
{
    account ac;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tACCOUNT HOLDER LIST\n\n";
    cout<<"=========================================================================================\n";
    cout<<"A/c no.    NAME          SSN         Address             Total Balance     Interest Rate\n" ;
    cout<<"=========================================================================================\n";

    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        ac.report();
    }
    inFile.close();
}

//   function to deposit and withdraw amounts

void deposit_withdraw(int n, int option)
{
    int amt;
    bool found=false;
    account ac;
    fstream File;
    File.open("account.dat", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
    if(!File)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    while(!File.eof() && found==false)
    {
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
        if(ac.retacno()==n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            if(option==1)
            {
                cout<<"\n\n\tTO DEPOSITE AMOUNT ";
                cout<<"\n\nEnter The amount to be deposited";
                cin>>amt;
                ac.dep(amt);
            }
            if(option==2)
            {
                cout<<"\n\n\tTO WITHDRAW AMOUNT ";
                cout<<"\n\nEnter The amount to be withdraw";
                cin>>amt;
                int bal=ac.retdeposit()-amt;
                if((bal<500 && ac.retssn()=='S') || (bal<1000 && ac.retssn()=='C'))
                    cout<<"Insufficience balance";
                else
                    ac.draw(amt);
            }
            int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(ac));
            File.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
            File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
            cout<<"\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found=true;
           }
         }
    File.close();
    if(found==false)
        cout<<"\n\n Record Not Found ";
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Take everything after `//class ends here` and move it into your `.C` file

Comment: You already have declarations and definitions nicely separated, so it should be as simple as cut-and-paste the class function definitions into another file.

Comment: Just noticed something. The calls to `ignore` after the `getline`s may cause you grief. `getline` will eat the trailing newline from hitting enter on the keyboard, so the ignore will likely discard the first character of the next input. Might as well fix the bug now and save yourself time figuring out why the inputs aren't quite right later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its as simple as this:

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "account.h"

using namespace std;

//   function declaration

void write_account();   //function to write record in binary file
void display_sp(int);   //function to display account details given by user
void display_all();     //function to display all account details
void deposit_withdraw(int, int); // function to desposit/withdraw amount for given account

//   Main function

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int num;
    do
    {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"----------------------------------------";
        cout<<"\nWelcome to the First National Bank\n" << "of Parkland - Account transaction system ";
        cout<<"\n----------------------------------------";
        cout<<"\n\n\t01. Create Account";
        cout<<"\n\n\t02. Deposit";
        cout<<"\n\n\t03. Withdraw";
        cout<<"\n\n\t04. Select Account";
        cout<<"\n\n\t05. Print Accounts";
        cout<<"\n\n\t06. Quit";
        cout<<"\n\n\tSelect Your Option (1-6) ";
        cin>>ch;
        system("cls");
        switch(ch)
        {
        case '1':
            write_account();
            break;
        case '2':
            cout<<"\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin>>num;
            deposit_withdraw(num, 1);
            break;
        case '3':
            cout<<"\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin>>num;
            deposit_withdraw(num, 2);
            break;
        case '4':
            cout<<"\n\n\tEnter The account No. : "; cin>>num;
            display_sp(num);
            break;
        case '5':
            display_all();
            break;
        case '6':
            cout<<"\n\n\tThanks for using bank managemnt system";
            break;
        default :cout<<"\a";
        }
        cin.ignore();
        cin.get();
    }while(ch!='8');

    return 0;
}


//    function to write in file

void write_account()
{
    account ac;
    ofstream outFile;
    outFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary|ios::app);
    ac.create_account();
    outFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
    outFile.close();
}

//    function to read specific record from file

void display_sp(int n)
{
    account ac;
    bool flag=false;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\nBALANCE DETAILS\n";

    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        if(ac.retacno()==n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            flag=true;
        }
    }
    inFile.close();
    if(flag==false)
        cout<<"\n\nAccount number does not exist";
}


//    function to display all accounts deposit list

void display_all()
{
    account ac;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("account.dat",ios::binary);
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    cout<<"\n\n\t\tACCOUNT HOLDER LIST\n\n";
    cout<<"=========================================================================================\n";
    cout<<"A/c no.    NAME          SSN         Address             Total Balance     Interest Rate\n" ;
    cout<<"=========================================================================================\n";

    while(inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account)))
    {
        ac.report();
    }
    inFile.close();
}

//   function to deposit and withdraw amounts

void deposit_withdraw(int n, int option)
{
    int amt;
    bool found=false;
    account ac;
    fstream File;
    File.open("account.dat", ios::binary|ios::in|ios::out);
    if(!File)
    {
        cout<<"File could not be open !! Press any Key...";
        return;
    }
    while(!File.eof() && found==false)
    {
        File.read(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
        if(ac.retacno()==n)
        {
            ac.show_account();
            if(option==1)
            {
                cout<<"\n\n\tTO DEPOSITE AMOUNT ";
                cout<<"\n\nEnter The amount to be deposited";
                cin>>amt;
                ac.dep(amt);
            }
            if(option==2)
            {
                cout<<"\n\n\tTO WITHDRAW AMOUNT ";
                cout<<"\n\nEnter The amount to be withdraw";
                cin>>amt;
                int bal=ac.retdeposit()-amt;
                if((bal<500 && ac.retssn()=='S') || (bal<1000 && ac.retssn()=='C'))
                    cout<<"Insufficience balance";
                else
                    ac.draw(amt);
            }
            int pos=(-1)*static_cast<int>(sizeof(ac));
            File.seekp(pos,ios::cur);
            File.write(reinterpret_cast<char *> (&ac), sizeof(account));
            cout<<"\n\n\t Record Updated";
            found=true;
        }
    }
    File.close();
    if(found==false)
        cout<<"\n\n Record Not Found ";
}
```

account.h:

```
#pragma once

class account
{
    int acno;
    char name[50];
    int deposit;
    int ssn;
    char address[50];
    int intRate;


public:
    void create_account();  //function to get data from user
    void show_account() const;  //function to show data on screen
    void dep(int);  //function to accept amount and add to balance amount
    void draw(int); //function to accept amount and subtract from balance amount
    void report() const;    //function to show data in tabular format
    int retacno() const;    //function to return account number
    int retdeposit() const; //function to return balance amount
    int retssn() const; //function to return ssn of account
    int retintRate() const;
};
```

account.cpp:

```
#include "account.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

void account::create_account()
{
    cout<<"\nEnter The account No. :";
    cin>>acno;
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Name of The account holder : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(name,50);
    cout<<"\n\nEnter The Address of The account holder : ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin.getline(address,50);
    cout<<"\nEnter SSN of The account : ";
    cin>>ssn;
    ssn=toupper(ssn);
    cout<<"\nEnter The Initial amount(>=500 for Saving and >=1000 for current ) : ";
    cin>>deposit;
    cout<<"\nEnter The Interest Rates : ";
    cin>>intRate;
    cout<<"\n\n\nAccount Created..";
}

void account::show_account() const
{
    cout<<"\nAccount No. : "<<acno;
    cout<<"\nAccount Holder Name : "<<name;
    cout<<"\nAccount Holder's address : "<<address;
    cout<<"\nSSN of Account : "<<ssn;
    cout<<"\nBalance amount : "<<deposit;
    cout<<"\nInterest Rate : "<<intRate;
    cout<<"\nTotal Balance : "<<deposit+deposit*intRate;
}



void account::dep(int x)
{
    deposit+=x;
}

void account::draw(int x)
{
    deposit-=x;
}

void account::report() const
{
    cout<<acno<<setw(8)<<" "<<name<<setw(6)<<" "<<ssn<<setw(6)<<" "<<address<<setw(17)<<" "<<deposit+deposit*intRate/100<<setw(16)<<intRate<<endl;
}


int account::retacno() const
{
    return acno;
}

int account::retdeposit() const
{
    return deposit;
}

int account::retssn() const
{
    return ssn;
}


int account::retintRate() const
{
    return intRate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. C:\Users\Jay Yoon\OneDrive - Parkland College\Desktop\project2.o:project2.cpp|| undefined reference to `account::show_account() const'|  It said undefined.

Comment: The code as is here is working for me. what is `project2.cpp`? is that where your main is? Also what's your compile command?

Comment: yes.project2.cpp is main.  I am using code blocks. Is this a problem?

Comment: Worked just fine over here as well. Make sure account.cpp has been properly added to the project and is being compiled and linked.

Comment: yes, when you add a class from the codeblocks menu, make sure to check the boxes `debug` and `release`

Comment: Thanks for the help guys.